# Packager won't start

Tags: react-native

I guess I upgraded node at some point and now when I try to run the packager with `npm start` it's complaining with:

```
$ npm start
react-native start

Looks like you installed react-native globally, maybe you meant react-native-cli?
To fix the issue, run:
npm uninstall -g react-native
npm install -g react-native-cli
```

Node 5.1.0, npm 3.3.12 and react-native 0.15.0

Answer (score 23, accepted):

It looks like the preferred way to start the packager now for an IOS app is by hitting the run button in xcode itself or using the following command:

`react-native start`

Comment: I have found that hitting the run button in XCode isn't enough. That if I haven't got the server up and running with react-native start the app won't launch properly.

Comment: @flyingace - agreed, in my case the launch sporadically fails, or else takes minutes to start. however, when I explicitly run react-native prior to hitting the run button everything loads successfully in seconds.

Comment: Thanks, just running "react-native start" directly off the command line, rather than delegate the same call via "npm run start" worked a charm.

Comment: While this does work, you do loose access to the npm environment created by 'npm start'.This isn't an issue for the current script but, since I develop on multiple PCs, I had modified mine to use Bonjour to discover the packager and the only place I could find the application name was a variable defined in package.json... The answer by @user552403 worked for me.

Answer (score 9):

I'm using:

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "node node_modules/react-native/local-cli/cli.js start"
}
```

Answer (score 7):

I got the same error.

It turns out it's because **npm** finds another `react-native` inside `node_modules` due to being started with a vastly different environment.

So I changed my `package.json` to look like this:

```
"scripts": {
  "start": "$NVM_BIN/react-native start"
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Did you follow the instructions and do?

```
npm uninstall -g react-native
npm install -g react-native-cli
```

I say this, because I kept making the error of installing `react-native` instead of `react-native-cli`.

Answer (score 1):

export PATH="/Users/my-mac/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools":$PATH

./adb reverse tcp:8081

./adb start-server

./adb devices

Answer (score 1):

I've been in this situation or days, no solution yet, so I had to downgrade to Expo@19.0.0, and it worked

if you like to follow my steps:

- in `package.json` update `devDependencies`:

  - `"jest-expo": "19.0.0"`
  - `"react-native-scripts": "1.0.0"`
- in `package.json` update `dependencies`:

  - `"expo": "19.0.0"`
- in `app.json` update the sdkVersion to `19.0.0`

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I would use `npm start` or `react-native start` and it would install the debug version of my app just fine, but the packager wouldn't start.

I found out it was because another process was using my 8081 port.

Check what processes are using that port if you're not specifying another port with `lsof -i tcp:8081` in terminal, or any other tool to find out what processes are using what port.