# react native unable to run-android

Tags: react-native

I have followed guide here to setup react-native 0.23 https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started.html#content

I tried to run

```
react-native run-android
```

and got the following

> Looks like you installed react-native globally, maybe you meant
>   react-native-cli? To fix the issue, run: npm uninstall -g react-native
>   npm install -g react-native-cli

and I tried above command to uninstall and install but still getting the samething.

I google and found some solution at [Packager won't start](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33908314/packager-wont-start)

Tried:

```
"scripts": {
  "start": "$NVM_BIN/react-native start"
}
```

and

```
react-native start
```

both still didn't work. For iOS no problem as I fired up XCode to run it. I have also installed VirtualBox and Genymotion as emulator.